# How to check if a socket is alive

Tags: php, sockets

I have a small server (written in PHP) listening on a socket created with `socket_create` and accepting connections using `socket_accept`. All connections are scanned using `socket_select`, and whenever that call returns, the server either accepts a new connection of reads from the socket. When a client disconnects, the socket associated with it is returned by `socket_select`, and then the server is able to detect the disconnect by checking that `socket_read` returns an empty string.

So far it all is "by the book" and works well, but the problem is that if a client drops the connection (if, for example, it crashes), then its socket gets into the list returned by `socket_select` (as expected), but when the server calls `socket_read` on it, it triggers an error:

`socket_read(): unable to read from socket`

Obviously, I have to add some check on the socket before calling `socket_read`, but I couldn't find what that would be. What would be the way to check that socket? Please see also comments in the code.

```
define( LISTEN_ADDR, 0 );
define( LISTEN_PORT, 31415 );

/* Set up the listening */
$main_socket = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );

$ok = $main_socket
    && socket_set_option( $main_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
    && socket_bind( $main_socket, LISTEN_ADDR, LISTEN_PORT )
    && socket_listen( $main_socket );

if( !$ok ) {
    fprintf( STDERR, "You screwed it up!\n" );
    exit(1);
}


/* Here user connections are stored. */
$user_sockets = array();

/* Used to pass NULL by reference. */
$null = null;

while( true )
{
    $readable_sockets = $user_sockets;
    $readable_sockets[] = $main_socket;

    $r = socket_select( $readable_sockets, $null, $null, null );
    if( $r === false ) {
            fprintf( STDERR, "Socket error: %d (%s)", socket_last_error(),
                    socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) );
            continue;
    }
    /*
    var_dump( $r ) - always tells int, > 0
    var_dump( $readable_sockets ) - just shows an array of sockets
    var_dump( socket_last_error( $s ) ) - always int(0)
    */

    foreach( $readable_sockets as $s )
    {
        /* If this is the main socket, then we have a new connection. */
        if( $s == $main_socket ) {
            $user_sockets[] = socket_accept( $main_socket );
            continue;
        }

        /* If not, then a user says something. */

        $buf = socket_read( $s, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ );
        /* And here occasionally goes:
            "socket_read(): unable to read from socket"
        + description from the OS telling that the remote host has
        dropped the connection. */

        if( $buf == '' ) {
            /* <remove $s from $user_sockets> */
        }
        else {
            /* <process what the user has sent> */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have this: $readable_sockets[] = $main_socket; inside your while loop. Is it your intention to add this on every iteration of the while( true ) loop?

Comment: I would probably make two selects, one for the main socket and one for the user sockets. There is also a bigger problem that entire $user_sockets array gets copied at every iteration. Although this is not the main question, I would appreciate some tips on that too.

Comment: This may be useful as it suggests how to handle unexpected connection abort/closure: [manual/en/function.socket-read.php#8913](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php#89133). This suggests a similar 'technique': [manual/en/sockets.errors.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.errors.php).

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I haven't seen that page about errors. It is strange that suppressing errors is an official way of solving it. Maybe there is another?

Comment: I am as 'impressed' as you are, however, i cannot find anything about error handling, as regards 'sockets' while searching 'google' about PHP sockets. I would suggest you use the technique as mentioned in the manual for now.

Comment: As regards the 'user_sockets', i would reserve entry 0 for the 'main' socket, i.e. store a 'reference' to the 'main' socket in the first element of the 'user_sockets' array, and then just pass it around by reference or just use it directly in the 'socket_select' statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55233/discussion-between-gas-welder-and-ryan-vincent).

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the result of select, which must be done in order to know if there is any socket available to be read.

```
$r = socket_select($readable_sockets, $null, $null,  0);
if ($r === false) {
    /* socket_select  Error handling */
} else if ($r > 0) {
    /* At least at one of the sockets something interesting happened */
}
```

The select function will change the `$readable_sockets`  array in case there is something to be read, or it may be undefined or untouched in case of timeout.

Note: Be aware that some socket implementations need to be handled very carefully.

A few basic rules:

- *You should always try to use `socket_select()` without timeout. Your

  program should have nothing to do if there is no data available. Code
  that depends on timeouts is not usually portable and difficult to

  debug.*
- *No socket resource must be added to any set if you do not

  intend to check its result after the `socket_select()` call, and

  respond appropriately. After `socket_select()` returns, all socket

  resources in all arrays must be checked. Any socket resource that is 
  available for writing must be written to, and any socket resource

  available for reading must be read from*.
- *If you read/write to a socket returns in the arrays be aware
  that they do not necessarily read/write the full amount of data
  you have requested. Be prepared to even only be able to read/write
  a single byte.*
- *It's common to most socket implementations that the only
  exception caught with the except array is out-of-bound data
  received on a socket.*

There is no way to know when a socket crashed until you try to read from it, according to my experience `select` never return a crashed socket as candidate to read, except when a gracefully close or shutdown is done at the other end. One thing you can do is to have a timeout for each socket, if the socket has no activity during, let's say 30 minutes, then you may discard it.

I'd also separate the user's socket from the main socket. Do a select for user's socket and dispatch their data and then do a select for the main socket and accept new connections. But it's up to you, if you want to check for the main socket in every single iteration, it's ok.

Comment: Dropped sockets _get_ selected (both on Windows and Linux), and then, I thought, there should be a way to check if a socket is still valid without triggering an error. The result of `socket_select` is always an integer, greater than zero (please see comments in the code). I don't have any explicit timeouts in the code, the select call returns only when there are changes.

Comment: @GasWelder Well, you don't check whether the select return an error or not. According to the manuals; `it's a good programming practice to always check the return code for values greater than zero before testing the descriptor sets.`  Select may be interrupted by a signal, and will return -1 and set `errno` to *EINTR*. To leave select to block indefinitely an assuming that it returns only when there is/are socket/s available to be read, from my point of view, is not a good practice.  It's up to you though.

Comment: The real code has that check, and the call always returns a positive integer. In the code above I just put it in the comments to try to emphasize that that check doesn't solve anything, but it seems I have only confused people with that. I'll edit the question and put it there.

Comment: @GasWelder if what you want is a method or function which let you know when a socket is dropped or has a broken connection, then, the only way is trying to read from it. If the other part has closed the socket, either gracefully or the OS forced the close, then when trying to read from the socket it returns 0, if the socket connection is broken then it return -1. That is the only way to know when a socket is closed or broken. That's as far as I know, and I have looked into many documents searching for a better/different way. If you ever find a better way, would you please, let me know?